# Find a text and replace it with a value in Matlab

Tags: matlab, replace, find

I have some data which look like this:

[image: data]

I would like to pre-process the data in a way that I replace all `Mostly false` with `1`, `Mostly true` with `2` and `Definitely true` w/ `3`. Is there a find and replace command or what is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Please, no images of data. Put a code snippet with the actual data that we can copy and paste

Comment: Matlab works well with categorical variables that contain strings [Convert Text in Table Variables to Categorical](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/convert-table-variables-containing-strings-to-categorical.html). The easy path is to "import data" from the main window and declare the variables as categorical during the import process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a map object to do the mapping

```
m = containers.Map( {'Mostly false', 'Mostly true', 'Definitely true'}, ...
                    {             1,             2,                 3} );
```

Then for some example `data`

```
data = {'Mostly false', 'Mostly false', 'Mostly true', 'Mostly false', 'Definitely true'};
```

You can perform the conversion with

```
data = m.values( data );
% >> data = {1, 1, 2, 1, 3}
```

This assumes there will always be a match in your map.

Alternatively, you could do the operation manually (for the same example data), this will leave non-matches unaltered, and you could use `strcmpi` for case-insensitivity:

```
c = {'Mostly false', 'Mostly true', 'Definitely true'
                  1,             2,                 3};
for ii = 1:size(c,2)
    % Make the replacement for each column in 'c'
    data( strcmp( data, c{1,ii} ) ) = c(2,ii);
end
```